# Good practice : construction of a complex member from a lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, initialization

I sometimes have this pattern in my classes:

```
class Variant;
struct Foo
{
  int x; 
  int y;
};

struct Bar
{
  int first() const; 
  int second() const; 
};

class Bar
{
  public:
    Bar(Variant v)
    {
       // For brevity there are no 
       // tests in this sample code
       Bar aBar = v.get<Bar>();  // Variant::get is a slow operation
       m_theFoo.x = aBar.first();
       m_theFoo.x = aBar.second();
    }

  private:
    Foo m_theFoo;
};
```

I'd rather initialize m_theFoo in the initializer list. However, I do not want to call to `Variant::get` twice like this since it might be a slow operation:

```
Bar(Variant v):
   m_theFoo{v.get<Bar>().first(), v.get<Bar>().second()}
{
}
```

So I came up with this :

```
Bar(Variant v):
    m_theFoo{[&] () { 
            Bar aBar = v.get<Bar>();
            return Foo{aBar.first(), aBar.second()};
        }()
    }  
{
}
```

Basically, the initialization is done by a lambda that is called and returns the initialized member.

I want to know if this sounds like a good / bad practice, and if there are drawbacks to this initialization method. For instance, how much would weigh the lambda instantiation ?

Would it be better to make it a stateless lambda like this ?

```
Bar(Variant v):
    m_theFoo{[] (const Variant& v_sub) { 
            Bar aBar = v_sub.get<Bar>();
            return Foo{aBar.first(), aBar.second()};
        }(v)
    }  
{
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just forward your initialization to a function - you get all of the benefits without any of the weird looks your code might get by being a bit cryptic:

```
Bar(Variant v)
: m_theFoo(makeFoo(v))
{ }
```

with:

```
Foo makeFoo(const Variant& v) {
    Bar theBar = v.get<Bar>();
    return Foo{theBar.first(), theBar.second()};
}
```

Comment: Completely agree with this answer, but just to give the question asker some other good practices while we're all here: ideally makeFoo should only be declared/defined in the .cpp file, inside an anonymous namespace. This prevents the interface of Bar from being extended in even the tiniest way.